# How to fetch api when mounting of React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to display Nfts on my page but it gives and error like Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). So my nfts variable is an array but still mapping is not possible. Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Nfts = ({ walletAddress }) => {
    const sender = "abc";
    const apikey = "def";
    const [nfts, setNfts] = useState();
    const getNftData = () => {
        axios.get(``)
            .then(output => {
                setNfts(output.data.result)
        })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getNftData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <section className="my-nfts">
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    {nfts == '' ?
                        <><div className='mynft-title'>My NFTs</div>
                            <div className="empty-nft">There is no NFT to display</div></> : (
                            <>
                                {nfts.map((nft, index) => {
                                    if (nft.from == sender && nft.to == walletAddress) {
                                        <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={4}>
                                            <div key={index}>{nft}</div>
                                        </Col>

                                    }
                                })}
                            </>
                        )}
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Nfts;
```

So I beleive it doesnt render at the first time when page is loaded. But i might be wrong. What do you think I am making wrong? Thanks..

Comment: "So my nfts variable is an array"
This line `const [nfts, setNfts] = useState();` initializes `nfts` with undefined value, so your `nfts` variable is indeed not an array until your `getNftData` doesn't retrieve the data.

Comment: You might want to check the response whether it is an array or other type like json and console log them then decide course of action before mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the nfts State an empty array as initial value
For example

```
const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);
```

or

In the HTML use a conditional statement to not use map method if the nfts still undefined
For example

```
nfts && nfts.map(() => { ... } )
```

Also, I noticed that the API URL is empty. ( I'm not sure if you mean that because you don't want to show the API URL in the question or you missing that ).

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggest much cleaner syntax for you

```js
nfts?.map((item) => { ...item } )
```